# How to compound search in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

So I am parsing facebook webpage using flutter and selenium. I first parse using a class name to get a list of around 100 elements. Now I need to search elements within these elements. How  can I do that? Here is my code so far

```
        posts = self.driver.find_elements_by_class_name("lzcic4wl")
        postCounter = 0
        for post in posts:
          #search by class name inside this post object
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK It will be easier to make it in just one call using a css selector instead of searching just for the class name, and then filter again with another class name

```
self.browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".lzcic4wl .other_class")
```

Comment: But I want it to be classified in such a way that i get the comments for each post separately. So it should be a list of lists or something similar. Also,the second class has spaces in it. I tried replacing it with _ but it didnt work

Comment: I'm missing something here. css class names can not have spaces, i suppose there are two different classes. Post an example of the data you want to parse to make it easy make a propposal https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example